# Open data-ng-click function from url param

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm working on a web that has several links that redirect to external pages.
One of those external pages has a modal that is shown when you click on a button. I'm trying to avoid the click of that button and show the modal directly from my page.

That button opens the modal with this link:

`<a data-ng-click="open('functionShowModal')">open</a>`

I can't edit the source code of that external webpage.

I'm looking for something like `<a href="externalWebPage?openModal=functionShowModal">`

Comment: Is there any `id` associated with it ? can you create a custom click event and see if that works

Comment: There is no `id` associated and I can't create an event since I can't edit the source code of that webpage.